# Perceptions and relationships of 14-15th century Spaniards / Romani / Moors

Tags: spain, 15th-century, religious-history, 14th-century, islamic-hispania

What perceptions of the Romani people were held by the Moors who occupied Granada around the time of the Reconquista? What were the relationships like between the Moors, Romani and the Sephardic Jews who lived during the 14th-15th century?

Comment: Hi Robert and welcome to HistorySE,! What has your research shown so far? Where have you looked? Please help us to help you. Please review the [site tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://history.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people#Arrival_in_Europe

Comment: Romani didn't exist in Spain until the 15th century.

Comment: Thank you very much Albert Yagos, I appreciate the help. So, would it have been entirely impossible for the Moors to come in contact with any Romani at all after the reconquista?

Comment: @Robert It was impossible in the 8th century as you asked, but the Reconquista lasted until 1492. The first Romani people got into Spain in 1425 and until 1499 they were around 3,000.

Comment: @Robert - And a lot of moors remained in Spain until the expulsion of the Moriscos (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expulsion_of_the_Moriscos) in 1609. Therefore, there were both Moors and Romani for a time in Spain.

Comment: My apologies @Alberto Yagos. I got my dates mixed up in the question. Trying to research time lines for a project I'm working on. I appreciate your response. Thank you so so so much.

Comment: @Sam Russell. Edited. Thanks sir. Any feedback in regards to what relationships were like between the groups is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'Romani' people? Romans? Gypsies? Celtiberians?

Comment: Yes @Jos I mean Romani. You call them Gypsies. Do you have any information on how they coexisted and how the Moors viewed the Romani & vice versa.

Comment: @Robert the number of gypsies was insignificant.

Comment: @Jos, I didn't ask about the number of gypsies. I asked what the relationship between the Moors, Romani & Jews were like. Did they get along, how did they view each other, what trades could they possibly engage in, any possible understanding/conflicts between the groups. There's information on how the Catholic church viewed the Moors, Jews & Romani, but very little on how these unique groups perceived each other.  Hope this clarifies my question.

Comment: @Jos, the number actually helps a little. So if you do have the information, sharing it is appreciated.

Comment: @Pere Thank you very very much sir. I'm super grateful for the input.

Answer (score 1):

Alberto Yagos helpfully observed in a comment that Romani entered today's Spain in 1425. A [map from 1360](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Spanish_kingdoms_1360.jpg) is as close as I could easily find, but the Emirate of Granada is far south of the Pyrenean route over which the immigrants reached "Spain". Is there evidence that any Romani people were present in the Emirate?

I searched unsuccessfully in the Biblioteca de al-Andalus for contemporary mentions of Romani people, and likewise in "A Select Bibliography of Muslim Spain" for modern ones. Several papers on the interethnic relations of the time also fail to mention Romani people.

The site of the [Museo Cuevas del Sacromonte](http://sacromontegranada.com/museo/el-sacromonte/) reports (without citation) that in medieval Spain, Romani and Jews had a special link based on their shared marginalization. Their situations changed with the Reconquest and Inquisition when all groups but the Christians became undesirables. Tomás Calvo Buezas in ["España racista?: voces payas sobre los gitanos"](https://books.google.com/books?id=RZHRoBP9_K8C&lpg=PA135&ots=SVgiLv4PHI&dq=g%C3%ADtanos%20en%20espa%C3%B1a&hl=es&pg=PA13#v=onepage&q=1499&f=false) dates Spanish social conflicts with Romani back to a notorious "anti-gypsy" rule of 1499, as did [Ibtissem Cheriguii's thesis](http://dspace.univ-tlemcen.dz/bitstream/112/9026/1/cheriguii-%20ibtissem.pdf) on Romani cultural influence in Andalucia. Apparently, any Romani-Moorish conflict was far outshadowed by later Romani-Christian conflict.

According to the 1906 Jewish Encyclopedia, [Jews did fine](http://jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/6855-granada) in the last centuries of the Emirate of Granada, and the state even served as a refuge for Jews fleeing from the [pogrom of 1391](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Jews_in_Spain#Massacres_and_mass_conversions_of_1391).

Comment: Thank you so so so much! I'm eternally grateful @Aaron Brock